# Concept Question About Gaussian Surfaces and Electric Fields

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

A small conducting spherical shell with inner radius a and outer radius b is concentric with a larger conducting spherical shell with inner radius c and outer radius d. The inner shell has total charge +2q.

The question asks what the Electric field is r < a.

Excess charge within a conducting shell goes to the surface.  Why doesn't the +2q go to the surface that is touching the space where r < a.  Then there would be an electric field (and charge enclose exactly at that spot).  Why does +2q only go to the surface of b?

Comment: Can you please post a diagram? It can give more clarity. You can also show the charge distributions you think the shells have.

Answer (score 0):

If the charges would stay at the inner surface, you would have an electric field driving them to the outer surface. in a closed object it is allways the outer surface which is called surface,

Comment: Thank you!  Makes sense